# HTML Form Downloading Response of POST Request

Tags: html, forms, file, post, flask

I am trying to use an HTML form to execute a post request. I know that in general AJAX is probably a better way to go about this, but my use case is very simple and I have to upload a file in this form submission (which is really easy just using HTML forms). Anyways, everything works, but for some reason my browser is downloading the contents of my POST request response, which I do not want to happen. I want nothing to actually occur when I submit the post request other than the post request being sent out.

Here is the HTML portion of my code:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/action" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000"/>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*">
     <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

I am not sure that it is relevant, but I am using a Flask webserver and here is the response I am returning:

```
response = {"status": 200}
return Response(json.dumps(response), mimetype='applications/json')
```

The issue is that I keep having files downloaded from my browser with '{"status": 200}' in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Status : 200` indicates.

> The request has succeeded.

So an OK status response is sent to the location, `/action` as you have mentioned in `action="/action"`. So I'm guessing this is the view you wanted to send the POST request too.

I don't have the code for your `/action` view, but either :

- This is not the view you intended to send it too.
- It is the view you intended to send it too.

So if its not the correct view, what you can do is, use jinja templating and mention your view like this.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url_for('xyz')}}">
```

Notice how I use the `url_for()` in jinja templating to specify route.

And if its the correct view, i can answer the question by seeing your code for the view called `action`.
Most likely what could be wrong though is,

- your return function is erroneous. Check the return function again.